# Existence of solution of weak solution of Dirichlet Problem

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, elliptic-operators

I'm reading "Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications" by S.Kesavan and I have a doubt in existence of weak solution of Dirichlet problem.

There theorem is:

[image]

[image]

where 3.2.3 is

[image]

However, in the statement of Lax-Milgram, for $f \in V$, there exists a $u \in V$. So according to this, for $f \in H^1$, there exists a $u \in H^1$. This doesn't prove what we require.

[image]

How does the conclusion follow?

Comment: Equation (3.2.3) is missing.

Comment: @Federico, I'm sorry. I have added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing link is the fact that for $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ fixed, the right hand side of (3.2.3) is a bounded linear functional on $H_0^1(\Omega)$. So, by Riesz representation there exists one $\hat f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ for which

$$
\int_\Omega fv =(\hat f,v)_{H_0^1}.
$$

Since the inequalities verified in the text for $a(u,v)$ hold true in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, then you can apply Lax-Milgram in that space and obtain the required result.

Of course, I agree with you in that the proof as shown above seems only to address the case in which $f\in H^1(\Omega)$.